# Configuring a UIRefreshControl from within a UITableView: best practice?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have the following code and it works:

```
class PullToRefreshTableView: UITableView {
    init(style: UITableView.Style = .plain) {
        super.init(frame: .zero, style: style)
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var first = true
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        defer { super.layoutSubviews() }
        guard first else {
            return
        }

        refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func reset() {
        // Cleaning the table view here
    }

    @objc func pullToRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        reset()
        // Then loading more stuff here
    }
}
```

What bothers me about it is that because the `action` doesn't register when done in `init` I need to do it later. I am abusing `layoutSubviews` now with a `bool` flag and that works. However it's...less than ideal.

Is there a function or anything that I can override within the `UITableView` (it needs to be self-containing) that will only be called once?

After a bit of tweaking I got this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    defer { super.layoutSubviews() }
    guard !(refreshControl?.allTargets ?? []).contains(self as AnyHashable) else {
        return
    }

    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

It still makes me feel like typing apologies in comments though it's pretty clear about it's intent. And not 100.00% reliable since somebody might add a `self` targeting action to that control before `layoutSubviews` is called.

Comment: No @JustinM including it `defer` is exactly the same as making it the last statement in `init`, it really needs to go through `init`, do something else and only then I can attach it. So a `UIViewController` has `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` which are perfect for this kind of stuff. But regular `UIView`s don't have it.

Comment: Did you try refreshcontrol.addTarget code inside awakeFromNib method?

Comment: @Anand it's programmatically added

Comment: @DepartamentoB it's not exactly the same. didSet observers don't get called when you assign a value in the init method normally, but they do if you put it in a defer block. Also, I tested your code above in a sample project and the pullToRefresh function was getting called when adding the action in the init method.

Comment: @JustinM I tried it and it didn't seem to work. Also the linter threw a warning about it though it was also the last block of the `init` function anyway. I would like to investigate your claim about the `didSet` getting triggered this way as it would simplify some code I have. I also initialize everything through code, no storyboards used, perhaps that's a difference here and there. If you have a working solution post it as an answer.